# Syntax error on opening quotation mark

Tags: python, syntax-error, quotes, quote, quotation-marks

I'm trying to run a script for exercise 3.3 in the book Think Python:

Problem: Python provides a built-in function called len that returns the length of a string, so the value of `len('allen')` is `5`. Write a function named right_justify that takes a string named s as a parameter and prints the string with enough leading spaces so that the last letter of the string is in column 70 of the display.

I've worked a few kinks out of script so far and right now I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def right_justify(s):
    print ‘ ‘ * (70 - len(s)) + s

right_justify(‘allen’)
```

and when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
 File "/Users/Jon/Documents/Python/Chapter 3/right justify.py", line 5
    print ‘ ‘ * (70 - len(s)) + s
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What mistake did I make and what should I do to fix this script?

Comment: SHould be:  `print ' ' * (70 - len(s)) + s`

Comment: You may want to consider switching text editors. If you're using an editor like `TextEdit` that isn't designed for code, you're likely to end up with funny issues like this one. I personally recommend [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/), but there are alot of other great editors out there.

Comment: If you are on Python 3, you need additional parentheses: `print(' ' * (70 - len(s)) + s)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `‘` character is unrecognized by the parser. You need to use either apostrophes or quotation marks (`'` or `"`) for string literals:

```
print ' ' * (70 - len(s)) + s
```

For more information, see [Strings literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The character you're using

```
print ‘ ‘ * (70 - len(s)) + s
```

is a non-ascii apostrophe, and while you can use unicode literals in your code, you can't use them for single quotes. You need the ascii single quote, `'`, (also sometimes used as an apostrophe),

```
print ' ' * (70 - len(s)) + s
```

or a double quote:

```
print " " * (70 - len(s)) + s
```